# notificationclick is not fired for remote notifications

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, web-worker, web-push

I used `self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {})` in my service worker to listen on click of notification

> The notificationclick event is fired to indicate that a system notification spawned by ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification() has been clicked.

When I use `ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification` and click notification it triggered listener, But When I have a remote notification it not triggered, I have to set `actions` from server and If the user clicks action buttons it triggered, But if clicked the notification itself , it is not triggered

Is there any workaround?

Comment: `notificationclick` should work also for the click on the main notification, not only for action buttons. It works fine for me, so your problem is somewhere else in your specific code.

Comment: What is your browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

firebase-messaging.js has the following code.

```js
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.notification.close();
```

Define my notificationclick-function before the library is loaded.

```js
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
  console.log('notification open');
  // log send to server
});

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'xxxxx'
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: Nice! I also found difficulty getting this working on localhost with Google Chrome, though Microsoft Edge seems to work. I would also like to mention that importScripts past 9.0 may require the -compat versions. I haven't fully tested, but it seems that service workers don't fully support modular javascript yet.